# matrix equality about I+BA

Tags: matrix-equations

Can you help me prove the matrix equality below? 
$$I+BA = (I+B)(I-(I+B)^{-1}B(I-A)),$$
where $B, A$ are some matrix and $I$ is identity matrix. Should I use matrix inversion lemma?

Comment: The right side looks like $x\left(1-x^{-1}y z\right)$ so it equals $x-y z$

Comment: Where exactly are you stuck ?

Comment: Oh, really thanks. I was stupid to try to use matrix inversion at RHS. Your simple answer is good

Answer (score 1):

Simply expanding the RHS:
\begin{align*}
(I+B)(I-(I+B)^{-1}B(I-A)) & = (I+B) - (I+B)(I+B)^{-1}B(I-A) \\
& = I+B - B(I-A) \\
& = I+B - BI + BA \\
& = I + B - B + BA \\
& = I + BA.
\end{align*}
Here, we use the fact that $BI=B$ and $(I+B)(I+B)^{-1} = I$.

Comment: Good, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If $A=x$, $B=y$, $I=1$, then:

$$1+yx=(1+y)\left(1-(1+y)^{-1}y(1-x)\right)=(1+y)\left(1-\frac{y-yx}{1+y}\right)=$$
$$(1+y)\cdot\frac{1+y-y+yx}{1+y}=1+yx.$$